# Using parameter in function

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, global-variables

I use parameter in this code, but I get NameError.

File "statistics.py", line10, in click1.
question = list(my_statistics.values()).
NameError : name 'my_statistics' is not defined.

What's problem? How can I do??? (I don't want to use global variables.)

```
    from tkinter import *    
    import random      
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Statistics Study Game")

    question = 'question'

    def click1(question):
        question = list(my_statistics.values())
        question = random.choice(question)
        output.delete(0, END)
        entry.delete(0, END)
        output.insert(END, question)
        return question
    question = click1(question)

    def click2(question):
        entry_text = entry.get()
        output.delete(0, END)
        entry.delete(0, END)
        try:
            answer=my_statistics[entry_text]
            if answer ==question:
                answer = "정답"
            else:
                answer = "오답"
        except:
            answer = "해당 단어는 없는 단어입니다."
        output.insert(END, answer)
        return question
    question = click2(question)

    Label(window, text="문제의 답을 입력하고 엔터키를 누르세요.").grid(row=0,     column=0, sticky=W)
    entry = Entry(window, width=20, bg="light yellow")
    entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    Button(window, text="제출", width=5, command=click2).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

    Button(window, text="문제 보기", width=6, command=click1).grid(row=4, column=0,sticky=W)
    output = Entry(window, width=75, bg="light yellow")
    output.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, ipady=25)

    my_statistics = {"통계학":"자료를 모으고, 분석하고, 표현하고 해석하는 학문",
    "자료":"표현과 해석을 위해 모으고, 분석하고, 요약하는 사실과 그림들",
    "자료집합":"특정연구를 위해 모은 모든 자료",
    "원소":"자료의 조사 대상",
    "변수":"원소에서 관심의 대상이 되는 특성"}

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please (1) Post your code as text, not image, and (2) Post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: you are accessing a variable before defining it, move the variable definition to the top.